# .NET Assembly analyzer without single starting assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Various tools exist to display .NET assembly dependencies when starting from a single (entry point) assembly:

- [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)
- [.NET assembly dependency analyser](https://drewnoakes.com/code/dependency-analyser/)
- [Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx)
- [Powershell](http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=how-to-find-wrong-assembly-dependencies-via-powershell)

Is there a way to graphically display the dependencies between a set of assemblies, without a single entry point?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to create a dummy assembly that references your set (and nothing else) then run these tools on that. Otherwise, any simple graphing software is going to have trouble.